# My directive's 'template:' binding works but 'templateURL:' binding fails

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm working to make a calendar that I can drag and drop values into. I use `ng-repeat` to create a drop target for each day. It repeats a directive `<drop-target>` which you can see below. When I use `template:` within the directive, my data populates just fine, but I tried to move that template into a separate file and use `templateURL:` but my data doesn't display. It's still repeating the element and there are not console errors, so it seems like the binding is failing. **What can I do to maintain the binding?**

index.html

```
<div ng-repeat="day in thisMonth">
    <drop-target day="day"></drop-target>
</div>
```

drop-target directive

```
.directive('dropTarget', function(){
  return { 
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      day: '='
    },
      // This works fine
    template: '<div class="droptarget" id="day{{day.date}}">{{day.date}}<div ng-repeat="set in day.sets">{{set}}</div></div>',
      // This does not work 
    templateURL: "../templates/calDay.html",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
       // event functions removed
    }
  };
});
```

calDay.html (failing external template)

```
<div class="droptarget" id="{{day.date}}">
    {{day.date}}
    <div ng-repeat="set in day.sets">
        {{set}}
    </div>
</div>
```

example data from controller

```
$scope.thisMonth = [
    {"date" : "2016-01-01", "sets" : ["Squat", "Push Ups"] },
    {"date" : "2016-01-02", "sets" : ["Deadlift", "Run"] },
    ...
];
```

**Solution**

Use `templateUrl:` rather than `templateURL`

Comment: likely the path isn't correct... look at ajax request made in browser dev tools network for clues

Comment: It's likely that ../ doesn't do what you think it does.  I can't find any official documentation, but google search seems to indicate that it will look one directory down from index.html, NOT one directory down from your directive js file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally when this happens it is because the path to the templatURL is resolving incorrectly.

I've had the best luck either bundling the templates in javascript so they are pre-cached with a known ID (url path) OR hard coding the full route from the root of the application.

You can verify the route that angular is looking for by using "Network" in developer tools.

Comment: I was using `templateURL:` rather than the correct `temnplateUrl:`